# Cleanup code for angular 2 service

Tags: angular, service, destroy

I've a question regarding the lifecycle of angular 2 services.
When a component's injector is created with all the specified providers, some of them might need a cleanup logic (for instance to clearTimeouts, or cancel some asynchronous XMLHTTP request). Since there is no lifecycle for services in the injector provider, the workaround is to manually call some 'destroy' method on each service inside the compnent ngOnDestroy. 
My question is - Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: nope, sorry....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are facing the same issue, we arrived on the same solution. **Creating a function** called destroy inside of the service class. Then, inside of the ngOnDestroy of the component **providing the service**, **call the service destroy function**.